# How can I access a pytest fixture by a string?

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest` fixtures can work on other fixtures by passing them in as argument:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def wrapper_fixture1(fixture1):
    fixture1.do_something()
    return fixture1
```

Now I have multiple different fixtures `fixture1`, `fixture2` and `fixture3` which are different, but have similarities (e.g. a function named `do_something()`), which I want to apply to each of them.

But instead of defining three new fixtures (like in the example), I would like to define one generic fixture/function that create three fixtures which I can pass to a test. I was thinking about something like this:

```
def fixture_factory():
    for index in range(3):
        fixture = pytest.get_fixture('fixture%d'%(index+1))
        fixture.do_something()
        pytest.set_fixture('wrapper_fixture%d'%(index+1), fixture, scope='module')
```

Can this be done in some way? Or do I have to write three wrapper fixtures for each of the original fixtures, repeating the same code over and over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a fixture by a string, you can use `request.getfuncargvalue()` inside a test function or another fixture.

You can try something along those lines:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixture1():
    return "I'm fixture 1"

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixture2():
    return "I'm fixture 2"

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def all_fixtures(request):
    your_fixture = request.getfuncargvalue("fixture{}".format(request.param))
    # here you can call your_fixture.do_something()
    your_fixture += " with something"
    return your_fixture

def test_all(all_fixtures):
    assert 0, all_fixtures
```

Comment: Note that `request.getfuncargvalue()` does indeed work but it is better not to use it if you can.  It stops py.test from knowing which tests require which fixtures up front which can have subtle effects and introduce some parameterisation/collection oddities.

Comment: `request.getfuncargvalue()` is deprecated in favor of `request.getfixturevalue()`. Though this answer still works.  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at the `pytest_generate_tests()` hook (http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=generate_tests#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests) for your use case.